# Схема данных БД

Tags: база-данных

Задача звучит так: Вашими клиентами являются различные лица, о которых вы собираете определенную информацию (паспорт,Фио,телефон).Кроме того в зависимости от вида клиента (частное лицо, представитель компании, постоянный арендатор) и т.д.(список может расширятся). Вы собираете дополнительную информацию (например для представителя компании :название, адрес; для постоянного арендатора : день рождение), которая может отличатся для каждого конкретного вида клиента.
Как я делаю:

Есть таблицы:

- клиенты { id_паспорт, фио, телефон }
- вид клиента {id_вид_клиента, наименование}
- дополнительная информация {id_паспорт, дополнительная информация}

Я думаю это не совсем правильно, но не могу придумать как должно быть. Пожалуйста, поделитесь идеями?

Comment: Сколько доп филдов для каждого из типов может быть?

Comment: Таблица клиентов. Таблицы для значений статических атрибутов (словари). Плюс EAV-таблица для динамических атрибутов. Возможно, таблица с шаблоном наборов EAV-атрибутов в зависимости от вида клиента.

Comment: @AGS17, для каждого типа может быть разное кол-во , например можно взять такие данные : представитель компании {название компании , адрес }, постоянный арендатор {место работы, семейное положение, дата рождения}

Comment: Как вариант, использовать XML/JSON для дополнительной информации. Зависит от СУБД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я вижу структуру базы:

- `Clients` { `Id`, `TypeId`, `Name`, `Phone` }
- `ClientTypes` { `Id`, `Title` }
- `AdditionalFields` { `Id`, `ClientTypeId`, `FieldTitle`, `FieldType` }
- `AdditionalInfo` { `Id`, `ClientId`, `FieldId`, `FieldValue` }

Где в `AdditionalFields`:

- `FieldTitle` - имя доп филда (например, `День Рождения`)
- `FieldType` - тип доп филда (например, `DateTime`)

В `AdditionalInfo`:

- `FieldValue` - значение доп филда (например, `2012-08-08`)

И потом на основе этих значений получать, собственно, эти филды.

[image: database scheme]

Comment: вариант понравился, но в этом случаи пользователю нужно будет где-то узнавать какие же доп поля вводить для выбранного типа клиента, т.е. получается для разных типов клиентов могут быть одинаковые доп поля

Comment: @All888 действительно, ваша правда. Обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо большое, помогли, появилась потребность вести архив с информацией об изменениях данных о клиенте, опять наткнулась на трудности в построении схемы, был такой вариант Архив{id, data, idAdditianalField, Old value , New value }, но получается что поля name и phane из клиента не попадают туда, может быть будут идеи ?

Comment: @All888 задайте новый вопрос и опишите проблему подробнее ([задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask))