# Расширение схемы данных БД

Tags: база-данных

Стоит задача : учитывать , что данные клиентов могут меняться и необходимо хранить архив изменений данных клиентов. 
[Ранее была решена задача о хранении данных о клиенте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/670606/%D0%A1%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%91%D0%94)

В результате получилось, что есть информация основная для всех клиентов(ФИО, телефон) , но существует еще и дополнительная информация, по типам клиента. 
Схема хранения данных о клиентах изображена [тут](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP6gq.png).

Проблема: думаю что нужно хранить только ту информацию которая изменилась, не целиком срез данных по клиенту, следовательно думаю, что нужно добавить таблицу Архив с полями {id изменений, data, id клиента, имя поля которое изменили(?), OLD value}. Если бы в таблице AdditionFields были все поля включая name и ФИО клиента , то взяли бы FieldId и все. Но получается, что есть часть полей в таблице клиенты + дополнительные поля и как вот так указать изменяемое поле в архиве, когда они разбросаны, никак не могу придумать, естественно чтобы не было избыточности данных. Поделитесь , пожалуйста идеями ? может как-то по другому думать ?

Comment: Я бы вместо изменения полей в бд просто помечал их как устаревшие, затем добавлял новые с актуальной информацией. Таким образом в таблице хранится вся история изменений записей. Вместо переписывания нового внешнего ключа всем зависимым полям можно новому полю с актуальной информацией присвоить id устаревшей записи. Имхо проще и лучше чем создавать новую таблицу с архивом полей. Не нужно будет менять архивную таблицу при изменении основной.

Comment: помечать как устаревшие это например дату добавить или столбец с булевским значением ? т.е нужно будет перебирать все данные о клиентах , чтобы найти клиента с пометкой актуальный? и при изменении например телефона клиента, нужно брать все поля и перезаписывать в новые ? с внешними ключами что-то не понятно, т.е. чтобы не добавлять новые строчки например в таблицу AddatinalInfo нужно взять новый id клиента и заменить во всех полях которые не изменялись , правильно понимаю ?

Comment: Не нужно ничего перебирать, вы же по ключу обращаетесь к полю. Еще другой вариант добавить столбец bool и время добавления записи (если нужно помимо порядка изменений знать время). При изменении записи добавлять поле со старыми данными, помечать его сразу как устаревшее и ставить старую дату. Затем вносить актуальную информацию в поле, на которое ссылаются другие записи.